# Manage mutiple OS commands across apis (need to start stop on user request)

Tags: go, ffmpeg, goroutine, go-fiber

The scenario is I have to start `n` number of rtsp camera stream using `ffmpeg` command. The user has option to start number of streams and can form tiler, so he can see many streaming cameras similar to (NVR live view).

I can start and stop stream using `os/exec` command with `context` and `ffmpeg` streaming command with it (which start's stream).

My question is is "how can I cancel a particular stream based on user's request" (in Python I can kill OS process using process ID). Is there any way to stop/start particular stream, any references will be helpful.

Comment: [cmd.Process](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Process).[Signal](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Process.Signal)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `context.CancelFunc` in a map and use it to cancel the context, which will in turn cause the child process to be terminated.

See the demo below:

**main.go**:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/utils"
)

type manager struct {
    wg sync.WaitGroup

    mu   sync.Mutex
    jobs map[string]context.CancelFunc
}

func newManger() *manager {
    return &manager{
        jobs: make(map[string]context.CancelFunc),
    }
}

func (m *manager) startJob(ctx context.Context, id string) {
    log.Println("start job:", id)
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()

    if _, ok := m.jobs[id]; ok {
        return
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "./do.sh", id)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    m.wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer m.wg.Done()
        err := cmd.Run()
        log.Printf("job: %s done. error: %v", id, err)

        m.mu.Lock()
        defer m.mu.Unlock()
        delete(m.jobs, id)
    }()

    m.jobs[id] = cancel
}

func (m *manager) stopJob(id string) {
    log.Println("stop job:", id)
    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()

    if cancel, ok := m.jobs[id]; ok {
        cancel()
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt)
    defer stop()

    m := newManger()

    app := fiber.New()

    app.Post("/start/:id", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        id := utils.CopyString(c.Params("id"))
        if id == "" {
            return nil
        }

        m.startJob(ctx, id)

        return nil
    })
    app.Post("/stop/:id", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        id := utils.CopyString(c.Params("id", ""))
        if id == "" {
            return nil
        }
        m.stopJob(id)
        return nil
    })

    go func() {
        err := app.Listen(":3000")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    <-ctx.Done()
    _ = app.Shutdown()
    m.wg.Wait()
}
```

**do.sh** (`chmod +x do.sh`):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while :; do
    echo $1
    sleep 1s
done
```

**Usage**:

- send a request to start a new job:

  ```
  $ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/start/1'
  ```
- send a request to stop a running job:

  ```
  $ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3000/stop/1'
  ```

**Note**: this is only a simple demo to show the idea. It's not fully tested. Use with caution.